# Firebase Cloud Functions: cannot deploy my function. Error: The "path" must be of type string

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

when I try to deploy my firebase cloud functions the process is interrupted by this error.

```
Error: The "path" argument must be of type string
```

What is this path making a reference to?

Comment: Can you share the code of your Cloud Function and add it to your question?